How do quants know which stocks to analyze?
I've been working through Hull's Options, Futures, and Other Derivatives, and I've a couple of things about how options are supposed to be priced, subject to different conditions. He talks about how (in theory) to price stocks with dividends, without dividends, etc. But unless I'm missing something, he doesn't make any kind of statement on which instruments a quant should choose for analysis. Even though the theory doesn't assume which stock you are working with, I doubt that's all there is to it. What other factors do quants consider when deciding which stocks to analyze and trade. Do they look through every single stock on the market and choose the ones that satisfy some other criteria that makes the analysis easier or more robust or something? Do they just use whatever stocks they're most familiar with already?

Generally quant approaches to stock investing are based on an extensive or top down approach where large numbers (thousands of) stocks are screened using relatively simple (computer applied)  criteria (as opposed to the intensive approach often used by traditional pm's where a few stocks are subjected to hand-crafted and  in depth analysis, company visits etc.). BTW the Hull book does not cover quant investing at all, it is only about derivatives, so it covers half of Quant Finance.

Options and quantitative trading strategies are too separate things, Option traders generally trade 30 to 60 days out so are not concerned with analysing stocks, apart from basic knowledge of going concern, and a lot of option trading is just done on big indexes or ETFs such as SPY, IWM, QQQ, because of high liquidity and no problems of going concern. Hull is a text for those in the banking industry and is not relevant to day traders or retail option traders. Introduction to Quantitative finance by Paul WIlmott  small trader $10,000  AL Sherbins How to price and trade options is very good.

Hull is not enough to start trading with as knowledge.It is mostly for academic or for a large financial institution framework.The standard reference books for option traders are  Options as a Strategic Investment by Lawrence McMillan, and Sheldon Natenbergs Option Volatility and pricing. And as mentioned above.

Futures are heavily covered in Hull they are not in the books mentioned above.
